# Reading in text files and removing words using sets and lists

Tags: java

I'm building a program that reads in a text file of stop words, then reads in a text file of tweets collected from Twitter. I'm trying to remove the stop words from the collection of tweets, so that i'm just left with the 'interesting' vocabulary, then in turn it prints them out to the console.

However, nothing is printing out to the console, so it's clear that it is not working... It was working prior to the importation of the test.txt file (when i was using a string created in the program, splitting it, then storing it in an array).

Any help with reading in the test.txt file and pulling out the stop words, then printing the listOfWords list to the console.

Any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RemoveStopWords {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    Scanner stopWordsFile = new Scanner(new File("stopwords_twitter.txt"));
    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));

    // Create a set for the stop words (a set as it doesn't allow duplicates)
    Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>();
    // For each word in the file
    while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
        stopWords.add(stopWordsFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    // Splits strings and stores each word into a list
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
        words.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    // Create an empty list (a list because it allows duplicates) 
    ArrayList<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate over the array 
    for(String word : words) {
        // Converts current string index to lowercase
        String toCompare = word.toLowerCase();
        // If the word isn't a stop word, add to listOfWords list
        if (!stopWords.contains(toCompare)) {
            listOfWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    stopWordsFile.close();
    textFile.close();

    for (String str : listOfWords) {
        System.out.print(str + " ");
    }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `while (stopWordsFile.hasNext())`, the second one will always return `false`:

```
// For each word in the file
while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
    stopWords.add(stopWordsFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
}

// Splits strings and stores each word into a list
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
    words.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
}
```

You should use

```
while (textFile.hasNext())
```

instead

```
while (stopWordsFile.hasNext())
```

at the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are reading words from your file twice:

```
while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) { // this will never execute as stopWordsFile has no nextElement left
        words.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
}
```

Therefore change your second while condition to :

```
while (textFile.hasNext()) { 
    words.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

copy your file into another file by reading it line by line and with each iteration (each line) tested if you have a line containing a 'stopword' if it is the case you remove it from the line and you copy the line in your file otherwise copies the line as it is